# Glueing product spaces - spheres and disks to make a torus in a sphere

Tags: homotopy-theory

I'm trying to understand the solution of the following problem
($S^1\times D^2/S^1\times S^1\approx S^2\vee S^3$ - homotopy equivalence) :
[Prove homotopy equivalence of two spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730888/prove-homotopy-equivalence-of-two-spaces) .

Implicitly there was used a fact that $(S^1\times D^2)\cup_{S^1\times S^1}(S^1\times D^2)=\partial D^4=S^3$ and I don't know how to prove it. Is this more general fact that $(A\times B)\cup_{A\times A}(A\times B)=\partial(B\times B)$ or some other generalization?

I couldn't add a comment, I hope it's ok to make a post like that.
Thanks!

Comment: There is no way that it would be $D^4$, since the dimensions don't match.

Comment: Ok you're right, I can see it better now. In fact, it became somehow intuitive for me. But still, is there more general fact of that kind? How to think about it?